# AJAX PUT call to database not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, put

I am trying to send data back to my database through the use of my WebAPI and it works correctly using Insomnia sending this JSON object using PUT method.

```
{
        "movieId": 11,
        "customerId": 6,
        "dateRented": "2017-12-13T22:50:53.93",
        "beenReturned": true
}
```

However, I am trying to do the exact same using jQuery and AJAX but it won't work and keeps giving error 500 back even though the payload looks correct.

```
 var object = {
           movieId: 2013,
           customerId: 5,
           beenReturned: true
};

    $.ajax({
            url: "/api/rentals/" + button.attr("data-rental-id"),
            method: "PUT",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(object),
            success: function () {
                    toastr.success("Movie returned.");
               }, error: function () {
                   console.log();
                   toastr.error("Unable to return movie.");
            }
    });
```

**Errors:** The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time relating your Error note to the code you have presented.  Is there code that you are not showing that is causing the error?  And your example has a dateRented on it, where as your code snipplet does not have that key on the `object` variable.  Is that accurate?

Comment: As @Taplar said, the error you mentioned is not directly related with the code section you shared.  If you can share the related code section of your endpoint, we may help.

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys. Been bugging me all day and as soon as I post here, I fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that my `"dateRented"` property has to be `"dateRented: new Date()"` because the string provided is not a DateTime object.